# DbContext class - ASP.Net.Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

How can I apply the `:base("name=connectionstring_name")` in ASP.NET Core?
Because my Visual Studio shows `cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'`   .

```
namespace SchoolDataLayer
{
    public class Context: DbContext 
    {
        public SchoolDBContext() : base("name=SchoolDBConnectionString") 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

```
public SchoolDBContext() : base("name=SchoolDBConnectionString")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error says you should pass `DbContextOptions` class instead of connection string.
The `DbContextOptions` instance carries configuration information such as:

- The database provider to use, typically selected by invoking a method such as UseSqlServer or UseSqlite. These extension methods require the corresponding provider package, such as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite. The methods are defined in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore namespace.
- Any necessary connection string or identifier of the database instance, typically passed as an argument to the provider selection method mentioned above
- Any provider-level optional behavior selectors, typically also chained inside the call to the provider selection method
- Any general EF Core behavior selectors, typically chained after or before the provider selector method

here is an example:

```
public class Context: SchoolDbContext
{
    public SchoolDbContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

for more information read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext